# Real image width with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the next function:

```
function setImagesWidth(id,width) {
    var images = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length;i++) {
        // If the real width is bigger than width parameter
            images[i].style.width=width;    
        //}         
    }       
}
```

I would like to set the css width attribute of all my img tags to a particular value only when the image real width is bigger than the attribute value. If it is possible, i would like a solution which does not use any particular framework.

---

`images[i].offsetWidth` returns 111 for an image of 109px width. Is this because 1px each side border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sergio del Amo: Indeed, if you check out my link you'll see that you want `clientWidth` instead.

@Sergio del Amo: You cannot, unfortunately, accept your own answer. But you do have an extraneous period in the "px" suffix, so let's go with this, including the `clientWidth` change:

```
// width in pixels
function setImagesWidth(id, width)
{
    var images = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("img");
    var newWidth = width + "px";
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i)
    {
        if (images[i].clientWidth > width)
        {
            images[i].style.width = newWidth;
        }                       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is, hopefully, enough sample code to give you what you want:

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("myImagesId");
var imageWidth = myImage.offsetWidth;
var imageHeight = myImage.offsetHeight;
```

That should give you the numbers you need to derive the solution you want. I think you can write the rest of the code yourself. :)

---

EDIT: Here, I couldn't help myself - is this what you are after?

```
function setImagesWidth(id,width) {
   var images = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("img");
   for(var i = 0; i < images.length;i++) {
      if(images[i].offsetWidth > width) {
         images[i].style.width= (width + "px");
      }
   }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Careful, it looks like you might rather want `clientWidth`:

http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Can i accept somehow this answer as the final one?

Since offsetWidth does not return any unit, the *.px* ending must be concatenated for the css attribute.

```
// width in pixels
function setImagesWidth(id,width) {
    var images = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length;i++) {
        if(images[i].offsetWidth > width) {
            images[i].style.width= (width+".px");   
        }           
    }       
}
```

Comment: Actually, you can accept your own answer after 2 days. Should be no problem after 7 years.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you, the reader, came here from google looking for a way to tell what is actual image *file* pixel width and height, this is how:

```
var img = new Image("path...");
var width = image.naturalWidth;
var height = image.naturalHeight;
```

This becomes quite usefull when dealing with all kinds of drawing on scaled images.

```js
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    var width = img.naturalWidth;
    var height = img.naturalHeight;
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "HTML Dimensions: "+img.width+" x "+img.height + 
                                                "\nReal pixel dimensions:"+ 
                                                width+" x "+height;
```

```html
<img id="img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Circle-withsegments.svg" width="100">

<pre id="info">

</pre>
```